# Implicit return with spread operator in .map() function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

How to use spread operator in implicit return wherein I'm removing one key value from the array of the object. I can use explicit return but I want shortcode and other possible solution of the scenario.

```
let array = [
{"sales":2341,"targetMet":false,"advertisment":true},
{"sales":981,"advertisment":true},
{"sales":3423,"targetMet":true,"advertisment":false},
{..},
{..}
];

let expectedArray = array.map(({targetMet,...rest}) => {...rest});

console.log(expectedArray) // should remove all targetMet keys
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're facing? So far as I can see your code works fine (and to the best of my knowledge that's the succinctest way of achieving what you're asking).

Comment: `{...rest}` must be `({...rest})` .... but it should work otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Just return `rest` no need to spread it again.

**Note**: To return an object from arrow function wrap object in `()`. But here you don't need that.

```js
let array = [
  {"sales":2341,"targetMet":false,"advertisment":true},
  {"sales":981,"advertisment":true},
  {"sales":3423,"targetMet":true,"advertisment":false},
];

let expectedArray = array.map(({targetMet,...rest}) => rest);

console.log(expectedArray)
```